# How to backup MBR on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, mbr

How can I backup my MBR (Master Boot Record) on Windows)?
I would prefer a built in tool (from Microsoft, etc.)

Comment: Use any direct-access software (WinHex, DMDE, HxD, etc.).

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/5-free-tools-to-backup-and-restore-master-boot-record-mbr/

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell, which comes with Windows 7 and newer. This script uses P/Invoke to access the native [`CreateFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) function, opens the first disk for direct reading, and saves the first 512 bytes of the disk to a file called `mbr` in the current directory.

```powershell
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class PInvoke {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
}
"@
$handle = [PInvoke]::CreateFile('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', 0x80000000, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0)
$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($handle, 'Read', $true)
$b = [array]::CreateInstance([byte], 512)
$fs.Read($b, 0, 512) | Out-Null
Set-Content .\mbr $b -Encoding Byte
$fs.Dispose()
```

To use it, save it to a PS1 file like `backupmbr.ps1`. After following the instructions from the Enabling Scripts section of [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info), you can invoke it from an administrative command prompt:

```
powershell -file .\backupmbr.ps1
```

If you have multiple drives, you can look in the Disk Management snap-in to find the number of the one whose MBR you would like to back up, then update the number in `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` to match.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no built-in Windows tools to backup MBR.

You can use third-party tool [Bootice](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html).

If you just want to be able to restore Windows' default MBR, then you don't need backups and there's an official MS tool to do that. Boot from a Windows installation media (Windows Vista or newer), press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and type `bootrec /fixmbr`.