# How to back up Master Boot Record from Windows 10 without installing vendor products?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, mbr, hard-drive-recovery

Is there a way to back up the master Boot Record (MBR) files(s) from Windows 10 of the disk where the same Windows 10 is installed without having to install any additional 3rd party tools?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a native way.

Comment: It will require a third party tool.

Comment: I just posted an answer to [an older question](https://superuser.com/a/1650006/380318) about this. However, with newer computers it's possible that your disk uses GPT rather than MBR. Are you sure it's just the 512-byte MBR sector that you have and want to back up?

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/backup-restore-bcd-file-windows-10/